# VMWare VPN on host conflict with VPN on guest machine

Tags: vpn, vmware

I have a Windows 10 host machine which runs a VPN and then on that host I have a guest machine on VMWare which has its own VPN. This works fine with ExpressVPN on the host.

However, I have set up a new host machine running Ubuntu and I cannot get the above setup to work. When the host runs a VPN, the guest machine loses its internet connection. I have tried toggling between bridged & NAT on VMWare. I have tried many different types of VPN services on the Host.

I am relatively new to Linux and not a programmer or particularly skilled with computers. Are there any settings I can try or experiment with to help resolve this?